# How to insert an array to mongodb using php?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

```
    update(array("loc1"=>$locations[0]),array('$set'=>(object)array("Users"=>(array("user_id"=>$user_id,"user_name"=>$Email)))));
```

I wrote the above code to insert user_id to the array users, after execution i got the result in mongodb shown below

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("5702cfd2c693b54008000035"),
"loc1" : "Anapara",
"loc2" : "Puthucurichy",
"loc3" : "Kadinamkulam",
"loc4" : "Kerala",
"loc5" : "India",
"Users" : {
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5702cfd2c693b54008000034"),
    "user_name" : "chunks@yahoo.com"
}
```

}

Here the keyword Users is not becoming an array, i mean i want it in this format (value of user in a square bracket):

```
    "Users" :[ {
                 "user_id" : ObjectId("5702cfd2c693b54008000034"),
                 "user_name" : "chunks@yahoo.com"}
             ]
```

What modification should i do in my php code to put the values in square bracket?

Comment: WHy are you typecasting the array to object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSON array (`[ ... ]`) can be saved from PHP if you use an array indexed by consecutive numbers (a list). So your code needs to be (I'll allow myself to make it more readable to illustrate better):

```
update(
    array("loc1" => $locations[0]),
    array('$set' => array(
         "Users"=> array( // this makes Users a list
             array("user_id"=>$user_id,"user_name"=>$Email) // this is your embedded object
             // here could go another embedded object separated by a comma
         )
    ))
);
```